# Calculated column incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a calculated column in SQL Server 2017 Developer as

```
ISNULL([Nominator]/NULLIF([Denominator]), 0) AS [Recidivation]
```

but this raises an error

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

This syntax works:

```
[Nominator]/[Denominator] AS [Recidivation]
```

I must be blind or something but have somebody any idea how I can't prevent division by zero in a calculated column as shown above?

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional `, 0`.  I also prefer the standard `COALESCE()` function.  So:

```
COALESCE(Nominator / NULLIF(Denominator, 0), 0) AS [Recidivation]
```

I also think the intention might be clearer with `case`:

```
(CASE WHEN Denominator = 0 or Denominator IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE Nominator / Denominator
 END)
```

Comment: I'm blind indeed... :-) Thanks.